# How is power/sample size calculation performed in R with only the maximum difference between means available?

Tags: anova

In Minitab, we can obtain the sample size/power result with only the maximum difference between the group means instead of ALL the group means.(As seen in the picture below.) How is this done? What are the formulas for the calculation of the sum of squares?

Also, I guess R shall also do this. However, it seems that functions such as power.anova.test and pwr.anova.test both require ALL the group means. Please, does someone know how Minitab does at the backstage and how can we do this in R?

[image]